# group document by field and merge fields

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have this document structure

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("63b6757dfa46345e268b7ba5"),
  "name" : "Blue Skinny Jeans",
  "sizes" : [45,46],
  "textile" : "Wool",
  "merchantCategory" : "Jeans",
  "tags" : ["Tag 1","Tag 2"],
  "sku" : "12161-2753930-5053177208071",
  "manufacturer" : "Hugo Boss"
}

/* 1 */
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("53b6757dfa46345e268b7ba4"),
  "name" : "Blue Skinny Jeans",
  "sizes" : [40,41],
  "textile" : "Polyester",
  "merchantCategory" : "Jeans",
  "tags" : ["Tag 2","Tag 3"],
  "sku" : "12161-2753930-5053177208071",
  "manufacturer" : "Hugo Boss"
}
```

Is it possible to **build a query** which **"groups" the documents** by name and **merge the fields** which are **not equal** (sizes,tags,merchantCategory,textile)

Comment: Both objects have same _id. It's not possible in the same collection. You should correct it with real datas.

Comment: haha, so think of they have not the same id. I will correct this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work,

```
coll.aggregate({"$group":{"_id":"$name",
                          "sizes":{"$addToSet":"$sizes"},
                          "tags":{"$addToSet":"$tags"},
                         ..
                         ..
                })
```